# INDEX / MATCH - Return results closest to TODAY()

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

How do I change the matching function to return the results in `Column G` in descending order from the `TODAY()` date entered in `C2`?

The function below works as expected, but the results aren't in the required order where the first match is the item / items that are closest to the date in `C2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$500,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$500>=$C$2,IF($B$2:$B$500<=$E$2,ROW($A$2:$A$500)-ROW($A$1),9^99),9^99),ROW()-ROW($A$1))),"")
```

An example Google Sheet can be found at this link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15adNP6hpUDh9w3Ai6C-nrkcMkYl_QfM6TwD9axLED3Q/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: You can't easily do this unless column `B` is sorted in ascending or descending date order.

Comment: If there are two or more values having same date in Column B but that is the closest to TODAY, how do you want to handle such a situation? Would you need to fetch all of them or only the first one?

Comment: @ patkim I would need to fetch all of them. Return them in order they first appear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what I understand best your question, I suggest a solution based on typical INDEX MATCH but in an Array Formula. Array formulas when applied to a large data set can be relatively slow.

If I correctly understand, you need to fetch
All Items in A that fall between start date and end date in order of closest to TODAY (C2) to farthest and in case there are duplicates (Different numbers but same expiry date), fetch them in the same order they appear in A.

See if this solution works for you.

In this example sample data is in Cols A B C D & E.

For sample data the rows are referenced from A2:A22. Please extend it to the desired value. If you have 1000 rows then set it to say A:2000 or so.

In F2 put the following formula and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the Formula Bar to create an Array Formula. Now drag it down up to the intended rows.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$22,IF(SMALL(IF(($B$2:$B$22>=$C$2)*($B$2:$B$22<=$E$2),$B$2:$B$22-$C$2+(0.0000001*IF(($B$2:$B$22>=$C$2)*($B$2:$B$22<=$E$2),ROW($B$2:$B$22))),9^99),ROW()-ROW($F$1))=9^99,9^99,MATCH(SMALL(IF(($B$2:$B$22>=$C$2)*($B$2:$B$22<=$E$2),$B$2:$B$22-$C$2+(0.0000001*IF(($B$2:$B$22>=$C$2)*($B$2:$B$22<=$E$2),ROW($B$2:$B$22))),9^99),ROW()-ROW($F$1)),IF(($B$2:$B$22>=$C$2)*($B$2:$B$22<=$E$2),$B$2:$B$22-$C$2+(0.0000001*IF(($B$2:$B$22>=$C$2)*($B$2:$B$22<=$E$2),ROW($B$2:$B$22))),9^99),0))),"")
```

Now in Col F it will fetch the desired data from A.

in G2 put the following simple VLOOKUP formula and drag it down upto the intended rows.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$B$13,2),"")
```

[image]

A solution without an Array Formula is also possible using a helper column though.

Update

---

The formula in Col F is same as what already posted above, however now Col B fetches Dates using a formula from H.

The formula in B2 is

```
=IFERROR(DATE(LEFT(H2,4),MID(H2,6,2),MID(H2,9,2)),"")
```

Drag it down up to the intended rows. This resolves the text data representing date in YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00 format in Col H to actual date. Col B is also formatted as Date.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Patkim. It is working except when `B:B` is retrieved using a formula like `=IFERROR(DATE(LEFT(H2,4),MID(H2,6,2),MID(H2,9,2)),"")` on a number string like `2028-11-30T00:00:00`

Comment: Please make sure that your Col B is indeed correctly formatted as Date. Also it seems that you have many more dependent sheets from which you are fetching data into the main sheet (screenshot of which you have posted in your question). You may like to share what results are you getting when your other dependent formulas are in effect in the main sheet.

Comment: I tried the solution on Google Sheet that you have linked and it seems to be working. I think it has saved the sheet on its own after I closed the browser. So in case that's not desired, please re-upload your original sheet for everyone's reference.

Comment: Yes `B:B` is formatted as date and is retrieved using `=IFERROR(DATE(LEFT(H2,4),MID(H2,6,2),MID(H2,9,2)),"")` Are you able to recreate my work flow where `H2` is in the following format: 2028-11-30T00:00:00

Comment: I have no reference of H2 in the screenshot that you have provided. Google Sheet that you have uploaded also does not have H column populated in any of its sheets. Your actual sheet seems to be considerably different from what you have shared.

Comment: I only refer to `H2` now because of the error encountered when `B:B` is a formula instead of plain text formatted to date. In the screenshot the original date is hidden because it is replaced by the formula which rearranges the date to make up `B:B`. I didn't know solutions would break down if `B:B` was a formula

Comment: @KyleUnderhill Please do not post XY problems (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Post what you actually want or it wastes your time as well as ours

Comment: I have uploaded a sample xls sheet in zip format to https://filebin.net/gee8w3gwykrt3p7a This includes formula on B extracting date from H. Please check it out if you desire. The file was virus free at the time of upload.

Comment: @ patkim is your solution working in the .xls? Are you able to update your answer accordingly? I apologize for not specifying that the data was a formula. I didn't know this would have effected the solution. I will be mindful in future questions

Comment: See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Note I will delete my other answer if you are satisfied with this one*

**Initial setup**

I populated my data to be exact to yours. Do note that since my Today cell is `=Today()` and that you posted this question a few days ago, my date is different than yours; however, the same idea still applies to what you are doing.

[image]

I now understand better that your `Today` field and `Months` field are simply inputs to drive the output. See how I now have them labeled to be clear.  Either way take a look at the output as it finds all data that is `greater than or equal to today` AND `less than or equal to today + number of specified months`

**Where all the magic happens**

So the big piece of this is what happens in my column I. The formula I have in Cell I2 is:

`=MIN(IF(C:C>=$E$2,IF(C:C<=DATE(YEAR($E$2),MONTH($E$2)+$F$2,DAY($E$2)),IF(COUNTIF($I$1:I1,C:C)=0,C:C))))`

**Make sure when entering this formula you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>**

**Explanation of formula and how it works**

At it's core this formula is basically modifying an array the whole time against our logic to a final array and then the minimum is found from that. See the diagram to outline what is being done:

[image]

So the first part is to filter if the array is greater than today:

`IF(C:C>=$E$2,C:C)` *Result is still an array at this point*

To expand this to filter out if the date is also less than today's date + x months we add that clause as well:

`IF(C:C>=$E$2,IF(C:C<=DATE(YEAR($E$2),MONTH($E$2)+$F$2,DAY($E$2)),C:C))` *Result is still an array at this point*

**Note that I used `DATE(YEAR($E$2),MONTH($E$2)+$F$2,DAY($E$2))` to calculate what `today + x months` actually is for a date as it is not accurate to simply say number of months * 30 since all months don't contain 30 days. This method takes this into account.

The next step is important and the piece you were missing - How to filter out items that were already found?  So in a similar method I take the current array I have and simply check back in the prior results since I will be dragging down this formula:

`PRIOR_CODE(IF(COUNTIF($I$1:I1,C:C)=0),C:C)`

The `$I$1:I1` part has the first part as static (dollar signs) to make it not change as we drag the formula down where the second part does not so it does change. This results in a moving range of all data prior to current cell.  I simply use a `COUNTIF()` function to report back how many are already reported for each item in our current array. The surrounding `IF()` states to only keep those with a `COUNTIF` equal to 0 which is the same thing as stating `not currently reported`.

Now if you follow all of it so far then you are in a good spot! The last part is to simply use `MIN()` to take the minimum value from our latest filtered array which results in what I showed initially:

`=MIN(IF(C:C>=$E$2,IF(C:C<=DATE(YEAR($E$2),MONTH($E$2)+$F$2,DAY($E$2)),IF(COUNTIF($I$1:I1,C:C)=0,C:C))))`

Now you can scroll this formula down and the only value that changes in it is this part:

`$I$1:I1`

It will become `$I$1:I1`, `$I$1:I2`, `$I$1:I3`, etc.

**The easiest part**

If you can do the above then reporting back the corresponding letter is child's play as all you need to do is either a `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX(MATCH())`

In my cell H2 I put:

`=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(I2,C:C,0))`

and simply drag down. It will look up the given letter for the found date.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explanation but I must say, with a large data set the function is extremely slow and unusable. Perhaps there is a way to incorporate your solution into the question's formula which was very quick at retrieving the results.

Comment: It is slow because of keeping the array going through the calculation. This is really the only way **without VBA** to accomplish what you are after, Since you didn't mention VBA in your original question I did not answer in that fashion

Answer (score 0):

Since the original poster is not happy with the speed of using arrays in my other answer, here is a VBA solution which can solve

```vb
Public Sub find_values_in_date_range()
Dim min_date As Date
Dim max_date As Date

Dim output_row As Integer

Dim number_column As String
Dim sheet_name As String
Dim min_date_cell As String
Dim number_days_forward_cell As String
Dim date_col As String

Dim output_number_col As String
Dim output_date_col As String

'~~~VVV~~~Define these variables to whatever you have in your own sheet!!~~VVV~~~~~

number_column = "B"
sheet_name = "Sheet1"
min_date_cell = "E2"
number_days_forward_cell = "F2"
date_col = "C"
output_number_col = "H"
output_date_col = "I"
output_row = 2 'initial row to output to

'~~^^^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^~~~~~~~~

'clear existing data from output columns
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet_name).Range(output_number_col & "2:" & output_number_col & "10000").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet_name).Range(output_date_col & "2:" & output_date_col & "10000").ClearContents

min_date = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet_name).Range(min_date_cell).Value 'define start date
max_date = DateAdd("m", ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet_name).Range(number_days_forward_cell).Value, min_date) 'define end date

For Row = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet_name).Range(number_column & "1").End(xlDown).Row
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet_name).Range(date_col & Row).Value >= min_date And ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet_name).Range(date_col & Row).Value <= max_date Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet_name).Range(output_number_col & output_row).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet_name).Range(number_column & Row).Value
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet_name).Range(output_date_col & output_row).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheet_name).Range(date_col & Row).Value
            output_row = output_row + 1
        End If
Next

End Sub
```

So Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to open VBA, click Insert, Module. Copy and paste this method in. Change the section where I define `number_column`, `sheet_name`, etc.., save your Excel workbook as `.xlsm` extension.

In order to run a VBA sub you can either:

- Navigate to the developer ribbon > Click `Macros` > Select your macro (in my case I named it find_values_in_date_range) > click `Run`
- Click Insert > Shapes > create whatever shape your heart desires. On the new shape, right click `Assign Macro` and then select find_values_in_date_range and click OK. Now whenever you click on the shape it will run the macro.

***If this finally satisfies what you are looking for, I will elaborate more into how the macro works so please let me know***